# Adding two rasters results in negative infinity and positive infinity

Tags: qgis-3, dem, masking, nodata

I'm trying to create a hydro-flattened DEM according to USGS specifications. I have two rasters, a DEM of my study area and a raster that only contains the water bodies that I have flattened so the pixels represent a flat surface for each of the lakes.

I've created a polygon mask that I've used to remove the lakes from the original DEM and used the saga:invertnodata tool to create an opposite mask that I used to generate the second raster containing only the flattened lakes.

When I try to combine the two rasters, my resulting image is blank with the only values recorded in the legend as 1.79769e+308 and -1.79769e+308 (for some reason -infinity is the upper bound but that may be trivial at this point).

I cannot for the life of me figure out why adding the two rasters (using simple addition in raster calculator) results in -infinity and +infinity. I suspect is has to do the masked values in each raster have a value of 'no data' but I've tried converting each raster's 'no data' values through gdal warp, translate, and a couple other tools that are supposed to convert no data values to a specified value.

Has anyone ever encountered this, or have another method to handle and convert 'no data' to 0?

Comment: In ArcGis I'd use cell statistics maximum of two, ignore nodata.

Comment: Could you check (`gdalinfo`) the extent of two input files? If they are not the same raster calculation tends to produce nodata raster.

Comment: The extents are identical, only difference between the two is one is float 32 and the other is float 64

Comment: Can you post `gdalinfo` output of each file (two input files and the problematic output layer)? By the way (if in doubt), QGIS raster calculator can handle calculation between Float32 and Float64.

Comment: The gdalinfo files for both are identical besides the Float32/64. I don't think it's an issue with the files, this result has now popped up after using a few different gdal tools and now I suspect it's a problem with the driver.